# How to create and add a new user to existing group in Active Directory via Java client

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, client, active-directory-group

I am a beginner and I try to implement client in Java for Active Directory. So far, I have written the following code:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class NewUser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewUser user = new NewUser("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "orgunit");
        try {
            System.out.print(user.addUser());
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static final String DOMAIN_NAME = "whatever";
    private static final String DOMAIN_ROOT = "dc=xyz"; // ?
    private static final String ADMIN_NAME = "CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=xyz,DC=xyz";
    private static final String ADMIN_PASS = "xxxxxxx";
    private static final String DOMAIN_URL = "ldap://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:389";


    private String userName, firstName, lastName, organisationUnit;
    private LdapContext context;

    public NewUser(String userName, String firstName, String lastName, String organisationUnit) {

        this.userName = userName;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.organisationUnit = organisationUnit;

        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");

        env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, ADMIN_NAME);
        env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, ADMIN_PASS);

        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, DOMAIN_URL);
        try {
            this.context = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem creating object: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean addUser() throws NamingException {

        Attributes container = new BasicAttributes();

        Attribute objClasses = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
        objClasses.add("top");
        objClasses.add("person");
        objClasses.add("organizationalPerson");
        objClasses.add("user");

        String cnValue = new StringBuffer(firstName).append(" ").append(lastName).toString();
        Attribute cn = new BasicAttribute("cn", cnValue);
        Attribute sAMAccountName = new BasicAttribute("sAMAccountName", userName);
        Attribute principalName = new BasicAttribute("userPrincipalName", userName
                + "@" + DOMAIN_NAME);
        Attribute givenName = new BasicAttribute("givenName", firstName);
        Attribute sn = new BasicAttribute("sn", lastName);
        Attribute uid = new BasicAttribute("uid", userName);

        container.put(objClasses);
        container.put(sAMAccountName);
        container.put(principalName);
        container.put(cn);
        container.put(sn);
        container.put(givenName);
        container.put(uid);

        try {
            context.createSubcontext(getUserDN(cnValue, organisationUnit), container);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private static String getUserDN(String aUsername, String aOU) {
        return "cn=" + aUsername + ",ou=" + aOU + "," + DOMAIN_ROOT;
    }
}
```

All what I need is to create and add an user.

I have got the following error:

> javax.naming.PartialResultException: [LDAP: error code 10 - 0000202B: RefErr: DSID 031007F3, data 0, 1 access points
>
> ref 1: 'xyz'
>
> ]; remaining name 'cn=bbb ccc,ou=orgunit,dc=xyz'

Comment: I think you have several issue with the code. You would need to use "unicodePwd" not userPassword with Active Directory. You also MUST use LDAPS when setting a password in Active Directory. This might help: http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Set%20Active%20Directory%20Password%20From%20Java

Comment: @jeemster thank you. So let's assume that I do not need any password. I have edited code in my post. I still have the same problem. It seems like problem is with this string: `cn=bbb ccc,ou=orgunit,abc.xyz.xyz`. Shouldn't it looks like `cn=bbb ccc,ou=orgunit,SOMETHING_HERE=abc.xyz.xyz` ?

Comment: I also changed DOMAIN_ROOT and now I have got the following error: `javax.naming.PartialResultException: [LDAP: error code 10 - 0000202B: RefErr: DSID-031007F3, data 0, 1 access points
 ref 1: 'xyz'
]; remaining name 'cn=bbb ccc,ou=orgunit,dc=xyz'` how I can check on Server if the dc which I provide is proper?

Comment: You will need to know what the FDN where you want to create the user and that it exists. I would recommend you obtain one of the LDAP Browsers, http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20Browsers, so you can see what your AD looks like from LDAP. You may also find this helpful: http://ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Determining%20the%20FDN

Comment: @jeemser thanks a lot! The problem was an incorrect DN variable. I reckon that you should add an answer with these links ;)

Comment: @ruhungry I am hitting this same exact error code. Can you explain the underlying problem and your fix in more detail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to know what the FDN where you want to create the user and that it exists.

I would recommend you obtain one of the LDAP Browsers, ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/LDAP%20Browsers, so you can see what your AD looks like from LDAP.

You may also find this helpful: ldapwiki.willeke.com/wiki/Determining%20the%20FDN